# Custom ErrorWebExceptionHandler.handle not being called

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have a custom ErrorWebExceptionHandler like the one described below:

```
@Configuration
@Order(-2)
public class GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    public GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Although the constructor is being called, the method **handle** is never triggered when an exception is thrown by one of the API methods and I still see the standard output:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-17T00:18:39.033+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/my/api/path"
}
```

Am I missing something or is there a better way to customize the exceptions globally?

Answer (score 0):

I end up changing the approach and implementing a *@ControllerAdvice* instead, similar to the class described below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {WebClientResponseException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleWebClientResponseException(WebClientResponseException ex, WebRequest request) {
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        
        return handleExceptionInternal(
            ex,
            ex.getResponseBodyAsString(),
            headers,
            ex.getStatusCode(),
            request);
    }
}
```